# restrict sending mail from gmail/yahoo in ipad

Tags: ipad, email, gmail, msn, yahoo-mail

I am designing an application for a society. 
In this application, there is a feature to send the contents of the particular page via mail by clicking of a button. There is no custom mail app designed. The feature uses iPad's native mail app to send the mail. 
I want to restrict the user to send the mail only from the society's domain registered mail account and not from his/her personal gmail/yahoo/msn id.
How do I put this restriction from my app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have no way of knowing or controlling what accounts they are using with the built-in mailer. You'll have to implement something custom to do this.

Comment: @CarlVeazey : yes, that's an option I have kept if I don't find a solution at all. But then I was wondering if a direct solution to this was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you send the email from your server, as you won't (and shouldn't) be able to control the user's email app. In other words, you allow the user to enter one or more email addresses into your app and then put the contents of the page into an email that you send from your email server to the specified addresses.

Comment: seems like there is lack of understanding on the problem on our part. I shall explain you the navigation.
1. I have my page open in the app which I wish to email
2. I click on the button to send a mail.
3. iPads native mail app is invoked where my society's mail is configured along with my personal yahoo and gmail id
4. I wish to restrict the user from using the personal id in the 'FROM' section. 
This restriction is something I am having a problem to put.

Comment: Why can't you link to an app page that uses your own email server rather than the user's email app?

Comment: Just another question if you can help. Can I trigger the LOTUS NOTES ipad app from my app to mail?
How do I go ahead with that ?

Comment: I believe you can only trigger the default email app/account, but I haven't researched in any detail. I suggest asking a separate StackOverflow question for this.

Comment: done that... stackoverflow.com/questions/14333753/call-lotus-notes-client-to-send-an-email-from-another-app/